# Check if the entered value is unique using onkeyup JS event

Tags: php, javascript, unique, onkeyup

I am validating a field called **client code for uniqueness**...

I have used **onkeyup** JS event for this purpose. 
But its not working fine when i type the keys very fast. On this

> onkeyup event

i am sending an ajax request to check whether the entered data already exists in the table or not.

Pls help if there is any alternative..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite vague in terms of the actual issue that you seem to be facing. But what I derive from it is that you are firing too many requests as you suggest rapid key presses!

---

As you would know, `Ajax` is like a normal page request, just done async, so it is bound by the same network latency, throughput and round trip constraints.

A clean way to achieve the functionality you need is to use a technique called **throttling**. One of the best `js` plugin for this purpose is located here:  http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/
It basically allows you to rate-limit your requests to the server, thus not choking the resources and providing a smooth UI.

---

Also, unless you wish to trap certain special keys like <kbd>ESC</kbd>, I would suggest using `keypress` or `keydown` events. Can't remember the specific reasoning for it, but just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is, that AJAX needs some time. Therefore, if your user types in very fast, you will send many requests to your server, and you will get many answers which you actually don't need.
One possible solution would be, that you make a timeout in your event. e.g. wait until the user hasn't typed a letter for about 500 ms or so. And after this, you send your Request to the server.
You will have less requests, and also your request can't get mixed up... .

Comment: yes.. it seems to be helpful.. but can you pls guide me.. on how to make this event wait..I am doing it in javascript.. so how it can be acheived..

Comment: @do_do_do - The technique to queue and release requests at intervals is called *throttling*. I have linked to a good resource that assist with this technique, with or without jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onkeydown` event and check `event.charCode`. That will fire even with fast on continuous-press typing.

Comment: oh. i am sorry. but this is not helping me.. it gives me the same problem.